# Creating multiple lists inside a list using its elements

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have an array/list like this:

```
 a =[5,8,9,6,5,4,5,6,1]
```

Then the Output should be:

```
 a =[[5,8],[9,6],[5,4],[5,6],[1]]
```

It's not necessary that I have to combine every two elements. It can be 2 or 3 or 4 but that's something I should be able to decide. I tried it multiple ways but was unable to achieve the result

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful:

You could be able to turn this into a function without problem

[image]